# Time conversion not working in case statement

Tags: sql, teradata

I know that Terada allows me to convert a string to a time value provided that I specify the format e.g.

```
SELECT '092712' (TIME, FORMAT 'HHMISS');

SQL>09:27:12
```

But I am having a problem in a case statement I coded (to transpose rows from a table into columns).

```
SELECT
...
MAX(CASE WHEN PARM_NAME = 'EndTime' THEN PARM_VAL (TIME, FORMAT 'HHMISS')  END)  TEST_END_TIME,
...
FROM MYTABLE
```

DB throws an error: "3707; Syntax Error, expected something like END keywork between the word PARM_VAL and (".

The END keyword is present on the same line. What am I missing??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add more brackets:

```
MAX(CASE WHEN PARM_NAME = 'EndTime' THEN (PARM_VAL (TIME, FORMAT 'HHMISS'))  END)  TEST_END_TIME,
```

Comment: Added brackets did the trick. Thank you!! Accepted and voted up.